My chips are too crispy!
Most questions about cooking chips ask "how do I make them more crispy?" mine is "how do I make them less crispy?"
I've been trying to make chips (as in traditional english fish and chips) following a triple cooking recipe.
The recipe (very simplified), is to chip some Maris Piper potatoes, simmer for 10 minutes, freeze. Fry at 130°C for 5-10 minutes, freeze again. Fry at 180°C for 5-10 minutes.
Perfect chips should be crispy on the outside with a soft fluffy inside. My problem is that during the first fry the chips dissolve almost to nothing - they're crispy on the outside and crispy all the way through with almost no-potato on the inside. They lose all their weight and the oil quickly becomes very brown and cloudy.
I've used the same recipe before without issue, so I'd really like to try to understand what has gone wrong with my last attempt.
(translation for Americans. Chips=french fries, 130°C = 265°F and 180°C= 360°F)

Cut the chips more thickly so that they don't cook through so fast? My mother used to fry them slowly at first, then turn up the heat to crisp them up (no intermediate freezing - we didn't have a freezer in those days).

What is the thickness of your chips? What are you using to measure the oil temperature?

Chips are not fries, they are chunky fries.

I suspect your par-boil step is too long. At 10 min, I think you've fully cooked the chips in the water.
